# Setting text and adding listener in android

Tags: android, listener, settext

I have made an Android blank project, then in the `activity.xml` page I added buttons and `TextView`s to the panel.

I want a code in the `activity.java` that changes the `TextView` in the activity if a button is pressed, how do I do that?

What I found out is the id in the .java file would be the following:

- `R.id.TextView1` for `TextView`
- `R.id.Button01` for `Button`

I want when I press the button the text is set to "hi", can someone help me with this please?
I am new to android and google search have failed me or use some weird way I don't understand. I need the basics.

Comment: but try it once by your self this is basic stuff anyway i have posted the answer.

Comment: this is the first time i ever program android, i am a java programmer (not advanced yet), i did not know about creating objects so i tried nothing.. i did not know how to get to it.. and R.id.textView1.settext(); was the only thing i was able t think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace this oncreate with yours and your code will work.

```
TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01); // get the button object
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1); // get the textView object

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { // set the click listener for the button
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText("hi"); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do:

```
    Button button; // ref to the button object
    TextView textView; // ref to the text view object

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // get the button object
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); // get the textView object

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { // set the click listener for the button
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText("hi"); // that's it!
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.setText("Hi");
      }
    });
}
```